# Passing an Interface collection

Tags: c#, generics, interface, collections

Suppose you have the following class:

```
class Car : IPainting
{
 ...
}
```

Then a function like this:

```
void AddCars(IEnumerable<Car> collection)
```

Then a code snippet like this:

```
Car bmw = new Car();
Car mercedes = new Car();

IPainting a = (IPainting) bmw;
IPainting b = (IPainting) mercedes;

IPainting[] paintings = new IPainting[] {a, b};

AddCars(paintings); // fails to compile
```

This of course doesn't compile because the AddCars() method accepts only a collection of Cars but it is what the 'paintings' array is made of.

I know that C# 4.0 will probably provide a solution for this. Is there any workaround today for it?

Thanks,

Alberto

Comment: C# 4.0 will not provide a solution for the code that you have here. You will never be able to pass something a type that is higher in the inheritance hierarchy to a method expecting something lower. As others have pointed out, your method would need to take in IPainting - not Car for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 4 will not allow the code that you wrote, since the method `AddCars` expects an `IEnumerable<Car>` which implements `IPainting`. This does not mean that you can pass *any* class implementing `IPainting` (you could for instance have a `class Bike : IPainting` that has nothing to do with the `Car` class whatsoever. However, it will allow the other way around; if you have `void AddCars(IEnumerable<IPainting> collection)` you can pass a `List<Car>` to the method.

Until then, you will need to stick to passing `Car` sequences to the method, by using some casting mechanism (such as `painting.Cast<Car>()` suggested in other answers).

Comment: Is the paintings.Cast<Car>() someway faster than a for loop that cast each object to the Car type? Thanks.

Comment: @devdept: Can't say; never did any performance comparisons on that. Would surprise if it it's not fast enough for most real-world scenarios though.

Answer (score 9):

Try using a generic method:

```
void AddCars<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IPainting
```

Comment: Will this solution allow both Car[] and IPainting[] arrays to be passed to AddCars() ?

Answer (score 4):

How about using Linq: `AddCars(paintings.Cast<Car>());`

Comment: We don't use Linq. We don't use databases at all. Where I can read more on the approach you suggested?

Comment: @devdept - that's linq to objects, not linq to sql.  It has _nothing_ to do with databases.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fundamentally flawed. Your class guarantees that all cars implement IPainting but there's no guarantee that all IPainting are cars.

You could likely make this work with some casting but I think you should reconsider your design.

```
AddCars(new Car[] { bmw, mercedes });
```

Comment: You are right, but I know that this is always true. Is there any way to enforce this? With a single Car object I can easily cast it to IPainting, the problem is I cannot do the same for collections.